# jwt token authorization in Karate DS

Tags: jwt, dsl, karate

Hi I am not able to get the jwt authorization using Karate DSL, it says 404 error
Might be i am missing on some syntax. here is my feature file. Any help on this is really great

Feature: JWT Token Feature

Scenario: Generate JWT Token

*configure logPrettyResponse = true
*configure ssl = true

Given url demoBaseUrl
And path 'ds-auth/jwt/v1/token'
And request { username: '****' , password: '****', validity: '1'}
When method post
Then status 200

Given def res = response
Then print 'The value of response is:', res.jwtToken

Given url demoBaseUrl2
And path 'federated-search/1/parent-child-query'
And request { query: '{"type":"AND","constraints":[{"type":"OR","constraints":[{"type":"FIELD_COMPARISON","field":"SUBJECT","value":"test","operator":"MATCHES"},{"type":"FIELD_COMPARISON","field":"MESSAGE_CONTENT","value":"test","operator":"MATCHES"}]},{"type":"FIELD_COMPARISON","field":"BODY_CONTENT","value":"software","operator":"MATCHES"}]}',messageType: '=Email='}
#And headers { Content-Type: 'application/json', Authorization: '[res.jwtToken]'}
And header Authorization = res.jwtToken
When method post
Then status 200

Answer (score 1):

```
*header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + res.jwtToken
```

Worked for me